# JS - Regex for one letter and 6 numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regular expression to test if an input starts with the letter "a" and is followed by 6 numbers. On the online validator seems to work, but on JavaScript doesnt.

This is the code:

```
function checkBookingReference (ref) {
    var regex = /(^a|A)([0-9]{6})/;
    return regex.test(ref);
}
```

The function returns true if I enter more than six numbers, and it shouldn't. Any idea why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That regex will return true if *anywhere in the string* there is a match. If you want to ensure the *entire* string matches it, then you'll want to use `^` to match the beginning and `$` to match the end.

```
/^(a|A)([0-9]{6})$/
```

Comment: Should use `i` flag instead of `alteration`. OP mentioned only `a` but he is checking for `A` too

Comment: To avoid confusion use `/^(a|A)([0-9]{2})$/` or `^a([0-9]{2})$/i`. How's that ?

Comment: This works fine. Thank you! And yes, @noob, it is also for uppercase "A".

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

```
return /^A[0-9]{6}$/i.test(ref);
```

Answer (score 0):

You nee to move the carat `^` outside the parentheses and use a proper group around the letters, then loose the trailing dollar sign `$`. Try this:

```
var regex = /^[aA][0-9]{6}/;
```

The parenthesis inside meant "not". Outside it means "beginning of string". The dollar sign meant "end of string".

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex object to specify the regular expression and then test it. Try this

`var regex = new RegExp("^a([0-9]{6})$","i");`
 `return regex.test(ref);`

Comment: Not the downvoter, but you say that you "need to use the regex object" which is not correct. Using the literal `/whatever/` syntax creates a `RegExp` already. Also, it is the regular expression that is wrong, not how it is being used.

Comment: Oh. Thanks I really didn't know that. Then what is the use of the object then??

Comment: And if you did want to use the `new RegExp()` call, it would look like this: `new RegExp("a([0-9]{6})$", "i");`

Comment: "Use the constructor function when you know the regular expression pattern will be changing, or you don't know the pattern and are getting it from another source, such as user input." - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: I get it now. Thank you so much for this info. Also @Sean thanks